# Magento 1.9.2.2 admin url showing blank page?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

**Magento 1.9.2.2** admin url display blank page.display errors code in `index.php` like this way

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but its not showing errors .Again its showing blank page
checked the var/log files but there is no error in this files.any one help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have no any error find then try below code add top in index.php file

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

after check it which line error showing it

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i got this error Cannot redeclare class Zend_Date_DateObject.
how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Cannot reach to my working laptop. I will process this issue when I be able to

Comment: ok..i will wait for u r reply

Comment: Any updates on this? I am having the same issue...