# Onepage checkout button is not working | magento 1.9 onepage checkout page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I have magento 1.9.3 and onepage is already installed with my theme. **Place Order button** which is the final button to submit an order is not working.

It is not disabled and in browsers it is not showing any kind of error as well

The form was working before but suddenly noticed that checkout button not working, no error is showing

can you help me to find the error please

Comment: you have checked in console ?

Comment: there is no error on console, do not know how to debug this

Comment: try this code in index.php and after check it 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266709/68695

Comment: if helpful above link  then above link in upvote